# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined using Angular and RxJs

Tags: angular, typescript, events, rxjs

I have an Angular application with in it a UserService and a guard. That guard is using the UserService to create a user and using that user based on its role to decide to return true or false. See the following code:

This is the guard:

```
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

  return new Observable<boolean>(obs => {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
      if (user.roles.includes(Roles.IT_PROFESSIONAL)) {
        obs.next(true);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        obs.next(false);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

This is the UserService Class:

```
  private static user: User;

  public getUser(): Observable<User> {

    if (!UserService.user) {

        UserService.user = new User();
        this.getGroups()
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
          response.value.map((v: any) => {  
            this.setRol(v); // use v to push v to the role array of the user
          });

          return of(UserService.user);
        });
    }
    else{
      return of(UserService.user);
    }
  }

    private getGroups(): Observable<any> { // Get groups for user
      return this.http.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf");
    }
```

When I run the app it says "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined". The problem is that the guard subscribes on the getUser observable, but this that I gets the user observable immediately. Why doesn't it wait for the UserService to return the user with the statement "return of(UserService.user)"?

Comment: thanks for your answer! Now it says this "Cannot set property 'roles' of undefined" in the setRole method which basically does this: "    if(v.mailNickname == "Employees") {
      UserService.user.roles = [Roles.IT_PROFESSIONAL];
    }"

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to subscribe to the observable in both instances. You could modify the notification using `map` or perform side-effects using `tap` operator and simply forward the observable. Try the following

**Guard**

```js
canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
  return this.userService.getUser().map(user => {
    if (user.roles.includes(Roles.IT_PROFESSIONAL)) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    return false;
  });
}
```

**UserClass service**

```js
public getUser(): Observable<User> {
  return (!!UserService.user)
    ? of(UserService.user)
    : this.getGroups().pipe(
        map((response: any) => // <-- not sure if `response` is modified here, if not use `tap`
          response.value.map((v: any) => this.setRol(v))
        )
      );
}
```

#### Update: Initializing `UserService.user`

```js
private static user: User;    // <-- don't initialize here
public getUser(): Observable<User> {
  return (!!UserService.user)
    ? of(UserService.user)
    : this.getGroups().pipe(
        tap((response: any) =>
          response.value.forEach((v: any) => this.setRol(v))
        )
      );
}

setRol(v: any) {
  if (!UserService.user) UserService.user = { /* valid user object */ } // <-- initialize here
  if (v.mailNickname == "Employees")  { 
    UserService.user.roles = [Roles.IT_PROFESSIONAL]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Now it says this "Cannot set property 'roles' of undefined" in the setRole method which basically does this: " if(v.mailNickname == "Employees") { UserService.user.roles = [Roles.IT_PROFESSIONAL]; }"

Comment: You've only defined the variable `user`. You need to initialize it to use it: Eg. `private static user: User = Object.create(null)`.

Comment: BTW if you're using this static property elsewhere in the app, it's better to define it as a multicast observable instead. Eg. `user: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>(1)`. This way you get to keep the data reactive.

Comment: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined. this is hapenning in the guard when the include comparison is done.. I have a feeling something is really wrong with my code

Comment: I don't think it even does an call with by using getGroups. Because the error is showing up too fast.

Comment: Obviously if you're doing `private static user: User = Object.create(null)` and if it's returned, there is no valid `roles` property available. It was only an illustration. You need to initialize the variable with a valid object instead. And no I wouldn't say there is something really wrong with the code. It's only a matter of initialization. Let me post a quick update.

Comment: When I do this in the same class:      this.getUser().pipe(map(user => console.log(user.roles)));
It prints nothing. But the setRoles method works.

Comment: Because you need to subscribe to trigger the request.

Comment: But the code above shows that I need to map in the guard class. I do that like this:         return this.us.getUser().pipe(map(user => { ...  Did I maybe understand you wrong?

Comment: In that case it must be subscribed to somewhere. If not the request wouldn't be triggered.

Comment: I now know what the problem is. Not the subscribe, but the pipe/map in the userservice returns the roles instead of the user!

Comment: That's a good catch, but I changed it to `tap` in the update since it shouldn't seem to return anything.